# Lean : Proof that \ not p \to (p \ to q) or similar false \to p

Tags: theorem-proving, set-theory, type-theory, lean, propositional-calculus

I am new at lean - prover and I am trying to solve the examples on the [online tutorial](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/propositions_and_proofs.html).

I am stuck at this example and I need to prove that "false implies q" or something like that.
My code is :

```
variables p q : Prop
example : ¬ p → (p → q) := 
    assume h : ¬ p,
    assume hp : p,
    --have hnpq : ¬ p ∨ q, from or.inl h,
    have hf : false, from h hp,
    --show q, from hf
    sorry
```

I do not think that defining hnpq can help because this proof is part of the (¬ p ∨ q) → (p → q).
In set theory I think that false implies everything.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: In Lean it is also true that `false` implies everything, see `false.elim`. So, you are almost there! (Hint: if you have `mathlib` installed, you can try `by library_search` and it will tell you if there is a lemma that proves the current goal under the available hypotheses.)

Comment: Thank you. It worked!! One question, that is mathlib!? Is it an extension for lean? Can you sent a link?

Comment: It's the main maths library for Lean. See https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib. The README contains links to installation instructions (which are somewhat nontrivial).

Comment: Thank you a lot!! I'll check it!